# Mostrar datos de mysql segun select

Tags: php, html, mysql, select

estoy aprendiendo a programar por mis propias cuentas y me tope con una duda, ¿puedo mostrar datos de una tabla MySQL según la opción que seleccione dentro de un select?, por ejemplo si selecciono el dpto 405, como hago para que la pagina me muestre el nombre del dueño que esta registrado en la bd para ese dpto, por ahora puedo mostrar el primer dato de mi tabla test, pero no puedo cambiar de dato segun el dpto seleccionado, adjunto parte de mi programa uwu, no se si se entiende, pero desde ya, muchas gracias por su tiempo!.

[image: fragmento de mi código]

Comment: hay muchas formas, una facil, seria que llames por ajax la informacion, otra seria que al hacer un cambio recarges la pagina mandando el id del select, otra seria que carges todos los detalles en la pagina y los ocultes y cuando haces un cambio en el select ejecute javascript haciendo solo la info del select visible

Comment: disculpa, podrías orientarme un poco mas, tendrás de casualidad algún tutorial o algo? es que llevo 1 semana aprendiendo y metiendo mano uwu, dejo constancia que la pagina solo la tengo con html, php y css, , gracias por tu comentario <3

Comment: Con este aprendes de una [https://codigofacilito.com/cursos/jquery](https://codigofacilito.com/cursos/jquery)